# Show that if the vectors $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\in \mathbb{R}^d$ are linearly independent, then...

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Show that if the vectors $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\in \mathbb{R}^d$ are linearly independent, then different linear combinations of them give different vectors.
I'm guessing the question is asking for $a,b\in \mathbb{R}^n$,
\begin{equation*}
a\neq b \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\ldots+a_nv_n\neq b_1v_1+b_2v_2+\ldots+b_nv_n
\end{equation*}
right? What do i do next? Thanks!

Comment: The contrapositive is pretty promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If different linear combinations give the same vector $v$, we have $v=a_1v_1+\dots+a_nv_n=b_1v_1+\dots +b_nv_n$ and then subtracting,  we get $(a_1-b_1)v_1+\dots+(a_n-b_n)v_n=0$, without all $a_i-b_i=0$.  This contradicts linear independence of the $v_i$.

Comment: Great thank you. Just one question what do you mean when you say without all $a_i-b_i=0$?

Comment: If we define $c_i=a_i-b_i$, then we have at least one $c_i\neq0$.  So we have a nontrivial linear combination of the $v_i$ equal to zero.

Comment: I'm still a little unsure how this proves what we need sorry for the hassle!

Comment: That's ok.  We get a nontrivial linear combination of the $v_i$ equal to zero,  which contradicts their linear independence.

Comment: Right of course thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

By contradiction assume otherwise, so there exists scalars $a_i$ and $b_i$ such that $a_j\neq b_j$ for some $j$ and $\sum a_i v_i=\sum b_i v_i$, then $$\sum (a_i-b_i)v_i=0$$ can you take it from here?